# Can we write mean $\mu$ for a given distribution in terms of RSS? Also standard deviation $\sigma$ in terms of RSS?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood, mean, mse

I am trying to express mean and standard distribution in terms of RSS so that I have a formula for likelihood in terms of RSS.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by RSS in this context. The usual RSS (residual sum of squares - $RSS = \Sigma_{i=1}^n(y_i - f(x_i))^2$) is the sum of squared differences  between data and estimates, and so is not relevant for a single distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Lynn, I understand your point now. In fact you are correct, I was having a wrong opinion on this whole thing. The question itself is meaning less as RSS is dependent on the predicted value whereas mean and standard deviation are dependent only on the data. I have another question, can we express LogLikelihood in terms if RSS? I see one on Wikipedia for a normally distributed data but, it doesn't follow from a scholarly/textbook resource. Hence, I doubt it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion